# Check member's roles in Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, roles

I'm trying to make my own Discord bot and I have to check if a member has a special role.
So I try this code :

```
    const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Guild } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content === "?start") {
    if (message.member.roles.cache.has("1033133978963689563")) {
      message.reply("Hi guys !");
    }
  }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot is ready !");
});

client.login(
  "token"
);
```

I try to find solutions but a lot of them are outdated or just doesn't work.

Comment: Can you tell what is going wrong with your code? Any unexpected behaviour or any errors?

Comment: @Caladan I don't have any error, the bot is online but when I type my command, nothing happens...

Comment: Do you have the [message content intent](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ)? Try `console.log(message.content)` and see if you get the intended output.

Comment: Yes, the message content intent is enable in the Discord Developer Portal. When I try another command like 

` if (message.content === "ping") {
message.reply("HelloWorld")
}`

it work.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using discord.js@13+ you need to use `messageCreate` event instead.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content === "?start") {
    if (message.member.roles.cache.has("1033133978963689563")) {
      message.reply("Hi guys !");
    } else return;
  } else if (message.content == "?ping") {
      message.reply("pong");
    }
});
```

Also, If it didn't work make sure you have `GUILD_MESSAGES` on your client's intent.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

At the end, if you are using discord.js@12 I highly recommend you to update to discord.js@13+